# Prevent Explorer sidebar from appearing when switching between tabs

Tags: view, tabs, explorer

I know there must be a way to do this but have been unsuccessfully trying to find a mention of it online. Whenever I switch between open tabs in vscode the Explorer sidebar automatically opens even when I have collapsed it prior. This drives me absolutely nuts, is there a setting that I have overlooked that prevents the explorer from opening every time that I switch between already opened tabs in my environment?

Closest setting seems to be Explorer:auto reveal - false but this does not prevent the Explorer from opening again when switching focus between tabs.